# CSS Normalize - HTML Emails

Tags: html, css, email, normalize-css

I've started building html emails for all browsers. Yes, the very primitive table-kind e-mail.

If I use the "css normalize" rule, would that solve all my issues with different browsers?

Comment: Basically...No. Emails aren't viewed in browsers as such, they are viewed in Email Clients...and they're all different. Outlook will look very different from Gmail.

Answer (score 3):

HTML Emails are always built using tables, but as Paulie says, NO is your answer. If you want to code for an email you can use this as  reference to what you can and can't use in different email clients. http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: That's the link I was looking for...but I thought it was a MailChimp one. LOL.